# Where is the System.Windows.Forms.Integration namespace?

Tags: wpf, winforms, interop

I can't seem to find it, trying to keyboard input in a wpf form spawned from a winforms form.  Found this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/442782b1-00a1-4e2e-9cc6-ae99b6699126/ But when I try to use it, VS2008 complains about not being able to find the System.Windows.Forms.Integration namespace.  I couldn't find a reference in the add references.

The only thing I can think of it maybe because it was a VS2005 project ported to VS2008?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You'll need to add a reference to WindowsFormsIntegration.  If you do a Add Reference in Visual Studio, it will be near the last DLL available in the .Net tab

On my machine it's located at

> %ProgramFiles%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll

Comment: Oooh, I was looking for System.Windows.Forms.Integration in the list, not WindowsFormsIntegration as one word.  Seems odd that they chose to name it that way.

Comment: @Davy8, I find it quite odd as well.

Comment: To expatiate, this dll is not found where you normally pluck dlls from in Visual studio. Rather, you have to go to a folder with a potpourri of dlls to get it. When you do an "Add Reference" in Visual studio, go to the file path JaredPar provided above and then add it to your project.

Comment: This hasn't helped me at all... I just keep getting System.Windows.Forms.Integration which has nothing like what I'm looking for in it

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio filters the available namespaces according to the type of project you chose.  If you need a namespace that is not listed, click the [Add...] button on the references tab of your project's properties.  This will pop-up the Reference Manager window.  Choose "Framework" from the list of Assemblies in the left-hand panel.  This will display all the Microsoft provided namespaces.  You will find WindowsFormsIntegration there.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the same problem.

While adding a reference to `WindowsFormsIntegration.dll` didn't work as this has no WF controls in it, I did find that adding a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

## Use newer:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\WindowsFormsIntegration.dll
```